# Malloc Issue : Double free or corruption (out) / Segmentation (core dumped) with Glut OpenGL

Tags: c++, c, malloc, glut, freeglut

i am  currently learning C++ and Glut / OPENGL.
(I don't have the choice I must use Glut even if it's old)
I keep getting errors like :

-Double free or corruption (out)
-Segmentation error (core dumped)
-Corrupted size vs prev_size

The program work sometimes, but most of the times i get these errors.
Please, I need help.

```
#include "graph.h"
#include "GLUT.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "eval2.h"

grapheur app;
static int run_once=0;
int x=0;
int i = 0;
double borne_inf=-10;
double borne_sup=100;
double pas=0.01;
double *tabX;
typejeton *tabY;
double *tabYfin, *tabXfin;
int *nb_valeur_ptr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));



int setup()
{
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("|     - Inserer borne inferieur : (-1000)       |\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    scanf("%lf",&borne_inf);
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("|     - Inserer borne superieur : (1000)        |\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    scanf("%lf",&borne_sup);
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("|     - Inserer le pas : (0.01)                 |\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    scanf("%lf",&pas);
    // Créer un tableau de X pour avec la fonction evenly(), demander le tableau de y à matis
// , trier le tableau de y pour enlever les erreurs et enlever les antécédents
// normaliser , puis tracer avec la boucle fort //

/// Tableau vide pour matis ///
    int nb_valeur=(borne_sup-borne_inf)/pas;
    //nb_valeur++;
    tabY = (typejeton*) malloc(sizeof(typejeton)*(nb_valeur+1000));
/// tableau de X///
    tabX = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double)*(nb_valeur+1000));
    *nb_valeur_ptr=nb_valeur;
    printf("%d valeurs\n",*nb_valeur_ptr);
    evenly(borne_inf,borne_sup,nb_valeur,tabX);

    Arbre a_test=(Arbre)malloc(sizeof(Arbre));
    a_test->jeton.lexem=FONCTION;
    a_test->jeton.valeur.fonction=EXP;
    Arbre plus=(Arbre)malloc(sizeof(Arbre)),b=(Arbre)malloc(sizeof(Arbre)),c=(Arbre)malloc(sizeof(Arbre));
    a_test->pjeton_gauche=plus;
    plus->jeton.lexem=OPERATEUR;
    plus->jeton.valeur.operateur=PLUS;
    plus->pjeton_gauche=b;
    b->jeton.lexem=REEL;
    b->jeton.valeur.reel=3;
    plus->pjeton_droit=c;
    c->jeton.lexem=VARIABLE;
    //c->jeton.valeur.reel=2;
    Eval(a_test, tabX,*nb_valeur_ptr, tabY);
    return 0;
}

void myKey(int c)
{
    double deplacement = app.echelle*0.25;
    switch (c)
    {
    case 27 :  //touche esc pour quitter
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 'z':
        app.centre.y -= deplacement;
        break;
    case 's':
        app.centre.y += deplacement;
        break;
    case 'q':
        app.centre.x += deplacement;
        break;
    case 'd':
        app.centre.x -= deplacement;
        break;
    case 'p':
        app.echelle = app.echelle / 1.5;
        break;
    case 'm':
        app.echelle = app.echelle * 1.5;
        break;
    case 'f':
        run_once=0;
    case 'Z':
        app.centre.y -= deplacement;
        break;
    case 'S':
        app.centre.y += deplacement;
        break;
    case 'Q':
        app.centre.x += deplacement;
        break;
    case 'D':
        app.centre.x -= deplacement;
        break;
    case 'P':
        app.echelle = app.echelle / 1.5;
        break;
    case 'M':
        app.echelle = app.echelle * 1.5;
        break;
    case 'F':
        run_once=0;
    }
}


void myDraw(void)
{



    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    logo_imt();
    setcolor(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
    axe(app);

    setcolor(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f);
//    affiche_graduation(app);

    cartesien p1, p2;

    if (run_once==0)
    {

        setup();
        run_once++;
    }

//      Liste *maListe = initialisation();
   // int tab[5]={0,1,2,3,4};

/*    for (int i=borne_inf;i<borne_sup;i+=pas){
      insertion(maListe,tabY[i]);
    }
    //for (i =borne_inf; i <borne_sup; i +=pas){
    //  if(tabY[i].lexem==ERREUR){

    //}
    //}
    */

    tabXfin = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * (*nb_valeur_ptr));
    tabYfin = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * (*nb_valeur_ptr));

    while(i < (*nb_valeur_ptr)){
        if(tabY[i].lexem==ERREUR){
            (*nb_valeur_ptr)--;
        }else{
            tabXfin[i]=tabX[i];
            tabYfin[i]=tabY[i].valeur.reel;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (i =0; i < (*nb_valeur_ptr); i +=1)
    {
        p1.x = tabXfin[i];
        p1.y = tabYfin[i];

        p2.x = tabXfin[i+1];
        p2.y = tabYfin[i+1]; // Remplacer fonction par evalatueur + analyse token
        normalisation(p1, app, &p1);
        normalisation(p2, app, &p2);
        setcolor(0.0F, 1.0F, 0.0F);
        ligne(p1, p2);

    }

    for(int i=0; i<*nb_valeur_ptr; i++)
    {
        (tabY[i].lexem==ERREUR)? printf("marshpa\n") : printf("%lf\n",(tabY+i)->valeur.reel);
    }

}



int main(int ac, char *av[])

{



    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("|              Guide de commande                |\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("|-----------------------------------------------|\n");
    printf("|                                               |\n");
    printf("|      - 'z' deplacement vers le haut           |\n");
    printf("|      - 'q' deplacement vers le bas            |\n");
    printf("|      - 's' deplacement vers la gauche         |\n");
    printf("|      - 'd' deplacement vers la droite         |\n");
    printf("|      - 'p' afin de zoomer                     |\n");
    printf("|      - 'm' afin de dezoomer                   |\n");
    printf("|      - 'esc' pour fermer la fenetre           |\n");
    printf("|      - 'f' pour changer les bornes et le pas  |\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------\n");



    app.centre.x = 0;
    app.centre.y = 0;
    app.echelle = 5;




    InitGraph(ac, av, "Essai Glut", 640, 480, myDraw, myKey);
    free(tabX);
    free(tabY);
    free(tabXfin);
    free(tabYfin);
    free(nb_valeur_ptr);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to try to analyze the problem? That would typically point you to the place where you use invalid memory.

Comment: `-fsanitize=address -g` and a good debugger are about to become your best friends.

Comment: Please supply a [mre]

Comment: Also, either you're compiling this as C++ (making the C tag irrelevant) or your C toolchain is highly questionable. `int *nb_valeur_ptr=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` is not valid as global initialization in C, and a C compiler should/would catch it if it has any smarts whatsoever. Either way, pick **a** language tag. there is no such thing as C *and* C++, What I just mentioned is one of the *many* places where those languages diverge.

Answer (score 0):

I bet on corruption rather that double free.

If we assume that `Arbre` is a pointer in `Arbre plus=(Arbre)malloc(sizeof(Arbre))`, the code allocates space for a pointer, but then uses it as a complete record:

```
plus->jeton.lexem=OPERATEUR;
plus->jeton.valeur.operateur=PLUS;
plus->pjeton_gauche=b;
```

This will inevitably overwrite additional memory and corrupt the heap. When later calling `free`, this corruption is detected.